# why wont the fav icon show up in IE on my asp.net-mvc site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, favicon

i have this line in my asp.net-mvc page.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/content/images/icons/favicon.ico" />
```

the favicon shows up fine in Firefox but it doesn't show up in IE8 at all.

any suggestions on why this doesn't work in IE8 ?

also, under RegisterRoutes, i have this:

```
   routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
```

i have tried everything [on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Standardization)  and it still doesn't seem to work for IE8

Comment: I vaguely remember something about IE wanting the favicon in the root of the web site, but I don't know where I read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article about favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) has a pretty good overview on how you specify the favicon and which file formats are supported.

The agreed standards is a bit in conflict with the de-facto standards. For example, the non-standard `rel` value `shortcut icon` has wider support than the standard value `icon`. You might want both a standard and a non-standard `link` tag to cover more ground.

Most browsers will pick up the favicon if you simply put it in the root folder, so that would be the best place to put it even if you also have a `link` tag that points to it.

Even if you do everything right, there is still no guarantee that the favicon will show up in any specific browser. Sometimes it simply doesn't work, for some unknown reason.

Comment: but in asp.net-mvc there is no real root folder so what would the link be?

Comment: @ooo: Yes, there is a root folder. Just put the file directly in the project folder.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an ASPX pages problem. I have never been able to show a favicon in any page for IE (all others yes Chrome, FF and safari) the only sites that I've seen that are the exeption to that rule are bing.com, msdn.com and others that belong to MS and run on asp.net. There is something that they are not telling us!

Even world-known sites can't show in IE eg: manu.com (most browsed sports team in the world) aspx site and fails to display the favicon on IE. manu.com/favicon.ico does show the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Use "shortcut icon" instead

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://mydomain.com/content/images/icons/favicon.ico" />
```

This wikipedia page [lists the compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

I would add that ideally for best browser compatibility the icon is best located in the root directory named favicon.ico if you are able to do this as most browsers will look there by default even without the `link` tag.

Comment: this didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Are you sure the favicon is actually being served up by navigating to the URL directly for instance?

Comment: Note that favicons can be cached by the browser, if you have navigated to your site previously without a faicon then when you add a favicon it might not show up immediately. You could confirm this by using fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Is this locally?

[Apparently](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/a6fb09ef-aa3e-4e9e-be44-edbfad322657): IE8 will never display the icon if the file is on your hard disk. It has to be on the internet. Other browers such as firefox will however show the icon even if they are on your hard disk.

EDIT

---

As this is happening locally and on the web-server - I would suggest saving down the stackoverflow icon to the same place as your icon and change the icon link accordingly. If it then works the problem is possibly with the file type of your icon file.

Comment: i dont follow . .i am referencing an icon on the web server

Comment: @ooo - you don't say whether the issue is in production or development in your question - that's why I flagged up the issue that happens locally.

Comment: gotcha . . nope . .issues happens locally, and on the web server :(

Answer (score -1):

For IE, the Favicon must be in the root.
e.g

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href='<%: Url.Content("~/favicon.ico") %>' />
```

Comment: Also, stop down voting everybody who trys to help you.